# MD RAID - disable NCQ

Tags: mdadm, md

Why is it recommended in a MD RAID (mdadm) to disable NCQ per-disk?
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/queue_depth

I read this tip in many articles regarding RAID tuning but nobody explains why.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answer.

Wikipedia states "`NCQ can negatively interfere with the operating system's I/O scheduler, actually decreasing performance`" and it refers to this article
http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/CSI500/Fal10/DiskArmSchedulingPapers/a2-yu.pdf

This article states "`Under a random workload, the I/O scheduler should be disabled, that is, noop, and NCQ in charge of scheduling requests entirely; when under a sequential workload, an I/O scheduler should take full charge of scheduling them instead of NCQ. It implies that the type of information that can help scheduling decision can vary according to the workload type.`"

Thus it seems to be a problem  under a sequential workload, but not under a random workload.

At conclusions it states that "`In the long run, we suggest that a new SATA 2 specification should contain a well-defined interface to fully control NCQ mechanism.`"

But this article is rather old (March 2010) and I don't know if it has been solved.

Comment: This guy did a test of NCQ on SSDs in 2015 and concluded that they do in fact use NCQ, and that any setting below 8 can be detrimental to performance: https://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2015/08/09/ssds-and-linux-native-command-queuing/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia article on NCQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing#Performance):

> NCQ can negatively interfere with the operating system's I/O scheduler, actually decreasing performance;[6] this has been observed in practice on Linux with RAID-5.[7] There is no mechanism in NCQ for the host to specify any sort of deadlines for an I/O, like how many times a request can be ignored in favor of others.